# Regular expression to replace (if|then)

Tags: arrays, regex, notepad++

I have some verse references in articles that I want to link to the adjacent verses file.

Example:

```
some text (Gen 2:15, 16), other text (Ex 4:12, 13) more.. etc.
```

I could replace the first one with the following regex:

```
\(<a href="/Verses.php?book=1&chapter=\1&vmin=\2&vmax=\3">Gen \1: \2, \3</a>\)
```

Here I fixed the "1" (book=) and the "Gen"

But I couldn't figure out how to use if|then so that I could give it all arrays of (Gen|Ex|Lev.. etc.), so that it replaces Gen with book number "1", Ex "2".. etc.

Comment: Regex for replacement has an error, there shouldn't be `Gen`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somewhere define what all the book orders are. And you'll need to use some sort of scripting language, not just a plain old regex. For example, you could do something along the lines of:

```
books = ["Gen", "Ex", ..., "Rev"]
```

...and then replace `book_name` with `books.index(book_name)+1`

The exact code/syntax obviously depends on which language you choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

With notepad++ you won't be able to get the order numbers.

But everything else is possible. You need to put each book on a new line:

find `\),` and replace by `\n`

Then use this pattern:

```
[a-z\s]+\(([a-z]+)\s+([0-9:]+)\,\s+([0-9]+)\)
```

and replace by:

```
<a href="/Verses.php?book=1&chapter=\1&vmin=\2&vmax=\3">\1: \2, \3</a>
```

you'll get the list of urls. Which then you can merge back to one line if needed.

The only problem is the book number.

Demo is here: https://regex101.com/r/qN8mO7/2